# Angular 2 : Typescript : Filter grid data based on provided filter condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eval

I am using dynamic column filtering in my grid (list). If I am going to apply static filter condition it works as expected. But when I tried it with dynamic column it don't work, some how I have to call with dynamic column as there should be multiple condition on same column also for multiple column. It doesn't throw me any error but not filter any record

**Filter Panel:**

[image]

**Static Filter (Working):**

```
this.GridData.filter(a => a.Scope == 'Framework');
```

**Dynamic Filter (Not Working):**

```
let _condition = "a.Scope == 'Framework'";
this.GridData.filter(a => _condition );
```

Required dynamic condition to work.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect that to do. It won't eval your code implicitly (thank god)

Comment: prepare condition statement which have dynamic rules and pass in filter like in above example (Dynamic Filter)

Comment: That isn't going to work, a string is not going to be automatically converted to a JavaScript expression and evaluated. That filter always matches every row.

Comment: how I can achieve above functionality? Is there any way?

Comment: What generates the filter logic in your actual program? Do you just want to intersect all conditions? Never mind, I see from the UI what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, I wants to combine all condition in one variable Or any other way if possible.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call method with in the filter Function as below.

```
let value = 'Framework';
this.GridData.filter(this.filterData.bind(gridData , value)); 

filterData(value,gridData) {
        return gridData.Scope == value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That isn't going to work, a string is not going to be automatically converted to a JavaScript expression and evaluated.

The function, `a => "a.Scope == 'Framework'"`, always matches all items since it returns a non-empty/non-whitespace string, which is a truthy value.

Rather than using dynamic evaluation (`eval`), and thereby taking on the severe security, readability, and toolability detriments that such an approach implies, I would recommend creating a fairly simple predicate builder.

In addition to being more reliable, extensible, and easier to maintain it provides a pleasant opportunity to highlight some of the elegant coding patterns that JavaScript enables and which TypeScript in turn allows us to eloquently specify.

Here's an example

```
export interface MemberInvocationExpression {
  kind: 'memberInvocation';
  memberKey: keyof Project; // project is row type
  args?: {}[];
  negated?: true;
  conjunction: 'and' | 'or';
};

export interface MemberComparisonExpression {
  kind: 'memberComparison';
  memberKey: keyof Project;
  compareWith: {};
  negated?: true;
  comparison: 'equal' | 'notEqual' | 'greater' | 'lesser';
  conjunction: 'and' | 'or';
}

export type GridFilterExpression =
 | MemberInvocationExpression 
 | MemberComparisonExpression;

export default class {
  gridFilterExpressions: GridFilterExpression[] = [];

  composeFilters(): (p: Project) => boolean {

    return this.gridFilterExpressions.reduce((composed, expression) => {
      // every element except the first element, must specify this.
      const conjunction = expression.conjunction;

      const predicate = predicateFromExpression(expression);

      switch (conjunction) {
        case 'and':
          return p => composed(p) && predicate(p);
        case 'or':
          return p => composed(p) || predicate(p);
        default: 
          throw Error('Invalid composition');
      }
    }, _ => true);
  }
}

function predicateFromExpression(expression: GridFilterExpression) {
  switch (expression.kind) {
    case 'memberInvocation':
      return predicateFromMemberInvocationExpression(expression);
    case 'memberComparison':
      return predicateFromMemberComparisonExpression(expression);
    case // other filter expression kinds....
      default: throw Error('invalid filter');
  }
}

function predicateFromMemberInvocationExpression(expression: MemberInvocationExpression) {
  const {memberKey, args, negated} = expression;

  const predicate = (p: Project) => p[memberKey](...args);

  return negated ? (p: Project) => !predicate(p) : predicate;
}

function predicateFromMemberComparisonExpression(expression: MemberComparisonExpression) {
  const {memberKey, compareWith, comparison, negated} = expression;

  const predicate = (p: Project) => {
    switch (comparison) {
      case 'equal': return p[memberKey] === compareWith;
      case 'notEqual': return p[memberKey] !== compareWith;
      case 'greater': return p[memberKey] > compareWith;
      case 'lesser': return p[memberKey] < compareWith;
      default: throw Error('Invalid comparison in filter');
    }
  };

  return negated ? (p: Project) => !predicate(p) : predicate;
}
```

Populating the array, `gridFilterExpressions` or whatever you choose to call it, is left as an exercise to the reader, but that is the easy part.
Well, here is an example based on one of your visible filters:

```
gridFilterExpressions
  .push({
    memberKey: 'Scope',
    compareWith: 'framework',
    comparison: 'equal',
    conjunction: 'and'
  },
  {
    kind: 'memberInvocation',
    memberKey: 'endsWith',
    args: ['test'],
    conjunction: 'or'
  });
```